# Cannot install ngx-cookie-service in angular project

Tags: angular, cookies, ngx-cookie-service

I am working on an angular project in where I need to use cookies.
I am installing ngx-cookie-service module from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service
But the module is not being installed, its showing the following errors

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency
> tree npm ERR! npm ERR! While resolving: chatbot-frontend@0.0.0 npm
> ERR! Found: @angular/common@11.1.2 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@angular/common npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~11.1.0" from
> the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm
> ERR! peer @angular/common@"^15.0.0" from ngx-cookie-service@15.0.0
> npm ERR! node_modules/ngx-cookie-service npm ERR!
> ngx-cookie-service@"*" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Fix the
> upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this command with
> --force, or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR! npm ERR! See
> C:\Users\Deepak Mane\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a
> full report.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Deepak
> Mane\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-01-01T13_59_03_695Z-debug-0.log

please suggest me a way to use cookie services.

Comment: One of the ways described in error message: `--force, or --legacy-peer-deps`.
Or update Angular version.
Or use proper version of `ngx-cookie-service` (11).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
npm install ngx-cookie-service@11.0.2
```

You need to align the library version with the angular version used in your project. You can find the proper version on the page you linked in your question.

Answer (score 0):

For version <9.x.x:

```
npm install ngx-cookie-service@2.3.0
```

Do not use --force, or --legacy-peer-deps as it will make your web application unstable.

After that in app.module.ts import these:

```
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

providers: [
  CookieService
],
```

If it still does not work then delete node_modules and npm install it again.